# TypeScript return type and automatic inference from parameters

Tags: typescript

**Example**

```
function greeter(person: string, test: boolean): string | number {
  if (test) return "Hello, " + person;
  return 1;
}

const hey = greeter("Foo", true);
```

If you place this in an editor and hover `hey` it says ([TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE4FN1XagFABxwGcEAuRIqVGMZAGkW0vICM44AbdAQzAEpylarUQAfRGBABbFjkQBvAFCJEMYIlxMofRBighUSAEQAJdBw5wGRxAGpEhVCTABuZbqwGkARjcBfRUUIBEpEAAt0AE9EAF4UDCwcXCMAMXYjBioQdD4XIA)):

```
const hey: string | number
```

I expected it to understand that it should be:

```
const hey: string
```

This can be constrained using with generics and constraints, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints. But this requires me to actively code this.

What I am wondering is why this cannot be inferred automatically by TypeScript?

Comment: ...because you annotated not a conditional or dependent return type? Generics may be useful here, but in this concrete case you define a function that works as two *different* functions depending on a boolean flag. Usually this is a design flaw anyway - just refactor this into two functions without a flag and call the appropriate one. If you insist on this implementation, use overloads (link in next comment - it's too long)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE4FN1XagFABxwGcEAuRIqVGMZAGkW0vKpHQEpzLraBuAKFCRYCFBiw4CxMhSo16jdM0TAAhgBsiHcmBABbAEY4BQ6PCRpM2PIVQkwXObQZMo5A3Djr0qsJ1k8yIgAPoi6hjiIAN78iIgwwIi4ruyIGFAgqEgARAAS6OrqcAzZiADUiLb2AnHpmUgAjAIAvvz8EAiUiAAW6ACeiAC8YlaS2QBintkuqGzsvEA

Comment: @SUTerliakov your example seems to be more nicely defined here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?q=506#example/conditional-types. Check getID().

My question is why cannot TypeScript understand the above code automatically, without having to do overloads or using constraints? I.e. it has the actual body of the code and can see that if `test` is true, it knows the return type will be a string by inference. I am not asking the "why" but the "how". I.e. is it a missing functionality TypeScript in the future could solve, or is it impossible for it to solve?

Comment: It does not know that. First, when you annotate the return type, no further inference can take place. If you remove the annotation, it still does not take conditional into account (type is inferred as `string | 1`) - inference is not sufficiently powerful for that. There's nothing wrong with doing such inference in theory (except for unneeded complication and potentially introducing even more unsafe "typing" than typescript has currently), but it is not implemented.

Comment: (and it's not "more nicely defined" IMO - I'd rather limit this crucial behaviour-changing flag to literal `true` and `false` instead of allowing union inference to avoid weird bugs, but it's my opinion only)

Comment: I agree with @SUTerliakov: A return type annotation is an explicit contract for the call signature and the compiler will not second-guess that.  On the other hand, if you don't annotate, the compiler will unfortunately never infer a generic-with-conditional or overloaded call signature from an implementation, which would almost certainly be intractable unless it was an opt-in codefix. I haven't found a relevant github issue to use as an authoritative source for this, though, so I won't write up an answer here. But that's the situation.

Comment: @SUTerliakov If I got it right, the answer to the question thus is:
"inference is not sufficiently powerful for that."

Being naive as I am about TypeScript, why is it so hard for TypeScript to properly set 'hey' to a string if 'test' is true? Is there a Github issue, that I could not find, that asks for this to be implemented?

They key of my question is:
"I.e. is it a missing functionality TypeScript in the future could solve, or is it impossible for it to solve?"

Comment: It is "a missing functionality", which is very unlikely to be implemented, at least in near future. The branch analysis exists, and real compilers (like `gcc`) do use it to e.g. eliminate dead branches. There's nothing theoretically wrong with inferring conditional or overloaded signatures, but it's a complex task with low benefits. (And it will never work with declared return type by design.)

Comment: Here's a [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), but in reverse direction. Currently TS compiler is not smart enough even to use such type, the reverse problem is even more difficult.

Comment: Appreciate the answers. I am fine if you want to add an answer regarding this, mentioning it is a missing functionality and what not. I'd mark the answer as answered.